# Why do trailing and leading zeros cause my function to return values i do not want?

Tags: javascript, function

This set of code i am providing should take any number i enter and reverse it. Currently the function works when n = 21.365 or n = 5698 but when n = 0456456456 it returns 41422397 instead of 6546546540 or when n = 056985 it returns 58965 instead of 589650 and when n = 016540 it returns 257 instead of 45610.

This is what i have written so far

```
//rules & limitations
//negative numbers should remain negative
//leading zeros should be removed
//the function can accept floats or integers
//the function will return integers as integers

function reverseNumberWithBuiltInFunctions(n) {
    return (
        parseFloat (
            n
            //convert the number to a string
            .toString()
            //convert to array of characters
            .split('')
            //reverse array of characters
            .reverse()
            //join reversed array of characters
            .join('')
        ) * Math.sign(n)
    )
}
```

I would like if n = 001 then 100 is returned or if n = 0456456456 then 6546546540 is returned. Essentially i am having trouble when leading or trailing zeros or both are included in "n" or it seems like issues arise when there is some sort of pattern to the numbers.

Also, why is it that when n = 016540 it returns 257?

Do you know of any solutions that could help improve the logic of the function with the given rules and limitations that would yield the desired results?

Comment: According to your comments above the function, "leading zeros should be removed", but then in your question you specify that you want to preserve leading zeroes and include them in the output. Which is it?

Comment: For your example of n = 016540, that is interpreted as an octal value equivalent to decimal value 7520. Which then gets reversed ('0257') and parsed to a float to get the final output of 257.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: you mention that this function should "take any number i enter". This implies that you are dealing with textual user input, which will always be a string. So I would recommend you add a type check to make sure you are getting a string, to ensure your function works as expected. e.g. `if (typeof n !== 'string') throw new Error(' reverseNumberWithBuiltInFunctions() only accepts numbers formatted as strings');`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is impossible if the inputs are integers or floats. There is no such thing as "leading zeros" on either integers or floats. If you use leading zeros to make a integer literal, it becomes an octal literal (changing the value; that's why `n = 0456456456` behaves the way it does, `0456456456` is just the octal way to spell `79322414`). If you parse a string with leading zeros to make an integer, they're simply ignored (`parseInt('000123')` produces the same value as `parseInt('123')`, namely, the value `123`). That's why `016540` becomes `257`:  the octal literal is equivalent to the decimal literal `7520`, and reversing it and parsing back to integer ignores the leading `0`, leaving `257`.

You can't preserve such leading zeros because they don't exist outside of string form. And you'll lose the trailing zeros on reversal because they become leading zeros in the new form.

Either work with strings exclusively, or accept that you'll lose leading zeros.

I'll note that your own rules in the comments specify:

```
//leading zeros should be removed
```

so it's working as expected here.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response. I figured it had something to do with number translations translations but i am new to javascript so i had no clue exactly what was happening so i thank you for your break down. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it in as a string as leading `0`'s in your numbers will not be interpreted as such.

For example:

```js
// Will always be evaluated as 1
let foo = 001;
console.log(foo);
```

If you were to supply `n` as a `string`, you may do it like this:

```js
reverseNumberWithBuiltInFunctions = n => parseFloat(n.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));

console.log(reverseNumberWithBuiltInFunctions('0456456456'))
console.log(reverseNumberWithBuiltInFunctions('056985'))
```

Comment: You are missing the key reason why `001 === 1`, which is that octal value 01 is the same as decimal value 1.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I do see that the other answer explains this reason very well, so I did not bother to add it.

Comment: this all makes sense after reviewing the answer from @ShadowRanger I am not too familiar with arrow functions as i am still learning so please forgive me if this is a silly question, but it seems like the only difference is that you have removed the `* Math.sign(n)` part. How is this producing the results you have shown? i know the "return" is implicit with arrow functions which is why you dont need it but other than that i am at a loss of understanding the fundamentals of your code snippet.